PCA and natural variation in the data
I wonder what the relationship between the PC (principle component) range and the natural variation in the data is.
To test this, I generate random values from two normal distributions with different standard deviations as below. I expect that the second set, generated from $N(0,10)$ has a longer range in the PC components but sometimes it is not. For example in the output below the PC ranges are:
        [,1]     [,2]
PC1 6.578774 6.231871
PC2 5.885548 5.859284

R code:
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123456789)

# Generate random data
n = 1500
x = matrix(rnorm(n), ncol = 10)
y = matrix(rnorm(n, 0, 10), ncol = 10)

# Perform PCA on both datasets
p1 = prcomp(x, scale. = TRUE,center = TRUE)
p2 = prcomp(y, scale. = TRUE,center = TRUE)

# Set up the plotting area for two plots side-by-side
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

# Plot PCA for dataset 1
plot(
  p1$x[, 1],
  p1$x[, 2],
  main = "PCA of Dataset 1. N(0,1)",
  xlab = "PC1",
  ylab = "PC2",
  col = "blue"
)


# Plot PCA for dataset 2
plot(
  p2$x[, 1],
  p2$x[, 2],
  main = "PCA of Dataset 2. N(0,10)",
  xlab = "PC1",
  ylab = "PC2",
  col = "red"
)

f=function(x){
  max(x)-min(x)
}
cbind(apply(p1$x, 2, f), apply(p2$x, 2, f))[1:2,]



Because you scale and center the data, you are doing the equivalent of generating uncorrelated standard binormal data.

Maybe you are thinking of restriction of range as in https://methods.sagepub.com/Reference/encyc-of-research-design/n388.xml.  Not that it would seem to apply directly to your situation.
